# While loop won't brake after it's contition becomes false

Tags: c++

I'm sorry if I'm not properly using this site, I'm new with programming, c++ and this place.
I have the next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char ch=0;
        while(ch<1||ch>4){
            cout<<"1)Calculos \n2)Fibonachi \n3)Calculos geometricos \n4)Salir\n";
            cin>>ch;
            system("cls");
        }
}
```

It is supposed to break the loop when the user enters a number between 1 and 4, but it just keeps looping. I have no idea why is this happening.

Comment: use `ch < '1' || ch > '4'`

Comment: If you want to get a number (int), why are you using a character (char)?

Answer (score 3):

Debug the code and check what values `ch` gets after the `cin` line! It think it will be the ASCII code of the input character that you typed and not (1-4) that you expect.

You could probably use `ch < '1' || ch > '4'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the input it in characters.  The ascii characters '1' and '4' are not equivalent to the integers 1 and 4.

If you are on Mac/Linux you can view the ascii table by typing `man ascii`.  If on Windows, there might be a way offline, or you can [find it online.](http://www.asciitable.com/).

In the table '1' is the integer 0x31 and '4' is the integer 0x34.  So you'll want your while loop to check for those integer values instead of 1 and 4.

Preferably, you could check for '1' and '4' and it should make the conversion for you, especially since `ch` is typed as a `char`

```
while(ch<'1'||ch>'4'){
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I learned a lot with it

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `ch` as char and `while(ch<1||ch>4)` is comparing int value if you want it to break the loop, declare `ch` as int. `int ch =0;`